# I am Trying to chain queuable class and write test class but i am getting error System.AsyncException Maximum stack depth has been reached

Tags: unit-test, error, queueable-apex

error which i am facing

> System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached

```java
public class AccountQueable implements Queueable{
    public void execute(QueueableContext qc){
        Account acc=new Account();
        acc.Name='Queable test';
        acc.Active__c='yes';
        acc.AnnualRevenue=2250.00;
        insert acc;
        if(acc!=null){
            id jobid=system.enqueueJob(new ContactQueable(acc));//here queueable chaing while account is inserted associated contact also inserted
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@istest
public class AccountQueableTest {
    @testSetup()
    public static void setup(){
        List<Account>acclist=new List<Account>();
        for(integer i=0;i<200;i++){
           acclist.add( new Account(name='test'+i));
        }
        insert acclist;
    }

    @istest public static void createAccount(){
        setup();
           List<Account>accounts=[select id,name from Account where name like 'test%' ];
                AccountQueable acountqueue =new AccountQueable();

        Test.startTest();
        system.enqueueJob(acountqueue);
        Test.stopTest();
        system.assertEquals(200,[select count() from account where Name like '%test%'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `acc != null` will never be false, given your current code. That `if()` statement currently serves no purpose.

Comment: here test class failing because of the error ,System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached can someone helpme to find solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you've provided so far, you shouldn't be getting a `maximum stack depth` error, but rather a `Too many queueable jobs added to the queue` error.

In tests, Salesforce only allows us to enqueue a single queueable. Any additional `system.enqueueJob()` calls inside of a queueable (i.e. chaining queueable classes) is not allowed.

The thing to realize here is that you're not (you shouldn't be) trying to test that Salesforce's handling of Queueable classes is correct (that's something we don't have control over, and should trust that Salesforce is running their own tests to ensure their feature works). You're trying to test that the code that *you have written* behaves as expected.

So instead of

```java
Test.startTest();
system.enqueueJob(acountqueue);
Test.stopTest();
```

Yoou should just call the execute() method directly

```java
Test.startTest();
// In most cases, people don't actually use the QueueableContext, so we can just pass
//   null in for that argument.
// If you do need to provide a QueueableContext, then having an inner class in your test
//   class which implements the QueueableContext interface is the way to go
acountqueue.execute(null);
Test.stopTest();
```

If your `ContactQueable` class doesn't enqueue any more jobs, then that's all you should need to do.

If you continue to chain queueables though, you'll want to do something like detecting that you're in a test context and then call the execute() method(s) directly instead of enqueueing. Yes, that means you might have a few lines not covered by tests, but that certainly is better than not being able to run tests at all.

Comment: hi @Derek F thanks for ur help it working properly now i am facing one more issue System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 200, Actual: 401 but in forloop i given only 200 why asserts failing

Comment: @maheshbabu You should make a separate question for that, and include the appropriate details. There's _something_ that you have which is creating additional accounts, but whatever it is, you haven't included that code/trigger/flow here.

Comment: error which i got ,that code already there in my post which is test this is error class,System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 200, Actual: 401